# Проблема при установке библиотеки aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, библиотека

При установке библиотеки aiogram происходит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть возможные способы её решения?

Comment: Способ решения указан прямо в тексте этой ошибки

Comment: Обнови pip. Там вроде написано
Python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Comment: Максим, пожалуйста, не используйте скриншоты в вопросе. Скопируйте информацию и прикрепите её обёрнутой форматированием. Так другие участники сообщества смогут найти похожее решение. + добавьте информацию о том на какой версии python и какими командами вы пытаетесь установить библиотеку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*После удаления программы 360 Total Security и очистки компьютера от мусора, библиотека установилась.*